# How many transactions could fit in a Bitcoin block pre-SegWit and post-SegWit?

Tags: segregated-witness, transaction-selection, blocksize

I am interested in how many transactions could fit into a 1MB Bitcoin block before SegWit and then afterwards. I can't find good information about this online and the figures seem to vary quite a bit.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Agree on the duplicate, especially after I updated the answer on the linked question to better cover this question as well.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I think it is worth expanding why I asked. I have seen in many text books that Bitcoin processes 7 tps based on the 10 minute block size and usually they will say approx 2000 per block. But I can't find any official confirmation. I think the answer linked suggests it's the wrong kind of metric.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a good metric. Perhaps payments per block would be a better metric, which is sometimes estimated as number of outputs in a block minus number of transactions in the block based on the assumption that almost all transactions have change outputs. However, there are meanwhile some wallets that explicitly try to craft transactions that don't require a change output, so that figure might also be getting less reliable.

Comment: Just for reference here is an example of the 2000 figure: https://www.bitstamp.net/learn/crypto-101/what-is-block-size/ I see it a lot, but wonder if it's just spread memetically.

Comment: Yeah, it does sound like someone just threw that out there and others thought that it sounds reasonable. I was wondering: did your question get answered comprehensively by the linked post? Otherwise, please feel free to edit this question here to specify what is still on your mind and flag for reopening. I'd be happy to hazard an answer (and vote to reopen) if it were the case.